# Vegas background jQuery plugin - in empty html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i tried to add [vegas plugin 2.1.3](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/setup/) to an empty html5 file, and it does not work.

I included js and css in the `<head>`:

```
<script src="http://zeptojs.com/zepto.min.js"></script>
<script src="vegas/vegas.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vegas/vegas.min.css">
```

and i put this in the`<body>`:

```
$("#example, body").vegas({
    slides: [
        { src: "/img/slide1.jpg" },
        { src: "/img/slide2.jpg" },
        { src: "/img/slide3.jpg" },
        { src: "/img/slide4.jpg" }
    ]
});
```

nothing happend.

Only thing is changed that i can see the code on the html website, as a text.

Did i miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems pretty vague but have you wrapped the Javascript in a 
 Tag?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#example, body").vegas({
        slides: [
            { src: "/img/slide1.jpg" },
            { src: "/img/slide2.jpg" },
            { src: "/img/slide3.jpg" },
            { src: "/img/slide4.jpg" }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

If you can physically see the code on the site, this is because the browser does not know to interpret this as code.